# Sending keystrokes and mouse clicks using Scala

Tags: scala, autohotkey

I've previously used AutoHotkey to send keystrokes and mouse clicks to automate interaction with GUIs and browsers. How do I send keystrokes and mouse clicks this time using Scala?

Comment: Try Java's [robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html ) class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `java.awt.Robot`.

```
val robot = new java.awt.Robot
robot.mouseMove(100,100)    // Cursor will jump to the top left of your screen
```

Note that you have to enter text keycode by keycode (see `java.awt.event.KeyEvent`).  This is pretty annoying, but you can write code to automate the pressing and releasing of keys.  (You do need to release *every* key you press!  It's emulating the keyboard....)

Comment: Thanks, I have been playing with the robot class and it is simple to send keystrokes and mouse commands. You're right that sending text isn't very elegant but using the clipboard makes it easier.

Answer (score 0):

JNA + Windows API

I had to send input to a background window and it worked really well for me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try the robot class first to keep the code platform independent but may revert to using a Windows API.